# Custom function that re-writes page title breaks when the Yoast plugin is activated

Tags: php, functions, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I recently had someone here help me write a custom function for the WordPress site that I'm developing so that it re-writes the page title when a 404 error is encountered.  It's been working exactly the way I'd intended -- however -- it stops working when I activate the Yoast plugin.  I don't get any PHP errors or anything, but my page title simply doesn't get re-written.

My assumption is that the Yoast plugin likely already hijacks the re-writing of the page titles, and that it is effectively overriding my custom function.

How would I update the custom method below so that it acknowledges the existence of the Yoast plugin, and so that I can leave the plugin active, yet still preserve the functionality of my custom method that re-writes the page titles?

Thanks,

-- Yvan

```
<?php
function theme_slug_filter_wp_title( $title_parts ) {
    global $parsed_address, $api_results, $wp_query;
    if ( ! $parsed_address ) {
        return $title_parts;
    }
    $title_parts['title'] = ucwords( $parsed_address ) . ' | AAA Real Estate';
    return $title_parts;
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'theme_slug_filter_wp_title' );
```

?>

Comment: Any takers?  It's been a couple of weeks now.  I realize that I don't really have many reputation points that I could offer up to put a bounty on this one, .. but is there anything else I can do to encourage folks to help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Well .. for those of you who might be interested, this is how I succeeded at overriding the Yoast plugin conflict with my 404 page titles:

1. I added a simple custom method to my mu-plugin file that retrieves the property address:

   function get_property_address() {
   global $parsed_address;
   return $parsed_address;
   }
2. I added this custom method for creating a custom Yoast variable to my functions.php file:

   function register_custom_yoast_variables() {
   wpseo_register_var_replacement( '%%propertyaddress%%', 'get_property_address', 'advanced', 'some help text' );
   }

   add_action('wpseo_register_extra_replacements', 'register_custom_yoast_variables');
3. I went in to my Yoast Settings (ie: Search Appearance > Special Pages > 404 pages) and added the "%%propertyaddress%%" custom variable to my 404 page title.